# ImapX Very slow in retriving gmail Inbox

Tags: c#, gmail, imapx

I am trying to retrieve gmail inbox list. It takes ages to retrieve the list.
Even after making min load call.

```
        client.Behavior.AutoDownloadBodyOnAccess = false;
        client.Behavior.AutoPopulateFolderMessages = false;
        client.Behavior.ExamineFolders = false;
        client.Behavior.MessageFetchMode = MessageFetchMode.Tiny | MessageFetchMode.GMailLabels | MessageFetchMode.GMailMessageId;


            client.Folders[name].Messages.Download("ALL", MessageFetchMode.Minimal, pagesize, skipmsgs); // Start the download process;
            return client.Folders[name].Messages;
```

Please advise how to achieve good retrieval speed.